# Output of conv2d in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

```
model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2))
```

We gave input as 400*400 image and this is the first layer in network, what kind of output will it produce??

Comment: You should be more specific about what exactly you want to know. Are you asking about the output dimensions? About the value range that will be taken? About the kind of information that is extracted using this operation?

Comment: output dimension and value of filter both

Answer (score 1):

```
if padding == 'same':
  output_length = input_length
elif padding == 'valid':
    output_length = input_length - filter_size 
return (output_length + stride - 1) // stride
```

So (400+2-1)//2 = (200,200) will be (H,W) respectively
and including filter (200,200,filter)

Answer (score 0):

I would like add to thefifthjack005's answer, this link :

http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/

Where you can find all the formula and much more informations on how Convolutional layers are working !

Here the import part for you :

[image]